# Proof by induction - summation inequality

Tags: induction

Prove by induction for $d,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ that
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}d^{k}\geq \frac{(n+1)^{d+1}}{d+1}.
$$

The base case for $n = 1$ makes $1 \geq 1$ which passes.
Then I found that 
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}d^{k} \cdot d^{k+1} \geq \frac{(n+2)^{d+1}}{d+1}.
$$
Now, here I am lost, I know that you can replace 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}d^{k}$$
with the right side of the original inequality, but I don't know how to use that to my advantage.

Comment: it is not correct for $d=1$: $n+1 \geq \frac{(n+1)^2}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$, LHS $=1+d$, RHS $=\frac{2^{d+1}}{d+1}$. It's not true that $1+d\ge\frac{2^{d+1}}{d+1}$ for all $d$.